# 'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private' error while overloading operator<< for std::ostram

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I've got a struct which looks like this:

```
sturct person
{
    string surname;
    person(string n) : surname(n) {};
}
```

I need to overload `operator<<` for `std::ostream` and `person`. I wrote this function:

```
std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream & s, person & os)
{
    s << os.surname;
    return s;
}
```

but I receive this errors:

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ios_base.h|788|error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private|
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_ios.h|64|error: within this context
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream|57|note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios&)’ first required here |

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::ostream` is not copy constructible, and when you return by value you are copy constructing. Although [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) means the copy might not actually be made, the compiler still requires that copying be possible.

The canonical return value for this operator is by non-const reference:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const SomeType& t);
```

Answer (score 3):

Return by reference:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(...)
          //^
```

Otherwise an attempt is being made to copy `s`, and `ostream`s are non-copyable (the error message is stating an attempt to access a `private` copy constructor).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot reference in return type:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream & s, person & os)
{
    return s << os.surname;
}
```